# I am unable to put a form in the middle of a div with CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to fit the input and button for the search form in the middle of my banner.

But this is what I get:

[image: Result]

Here the HTML:

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="logo"><strong>Magento Commerce</strong><a href="" title="Magento Commerce" class="logo"><img src="" alt="Magento Commerce" /></a></h1>
        <div class="quick-access">
            <form id="search_mini_form" action="/" method="get">
                <div class="form-search">
                    <label for="search">Search:</label>
                    <input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" maxlength="128" />
                    <button type="submit" title="Recherche" class="button"><span><span>Recherche</span></span></button>
                    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete">
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[
                        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Search entire store here...');
                        searchForm.initAutocomplete('/', 'search_autocomplete');
                    //]]>
                    </script>
                </div>
            </form>
            <ul class="links">
                <li class="first" ><a href="" title="Mon compte" >Mon compte</a> </li>
                <li><a href="" title="My Wishlist" >My Wishlist</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="My Cart" class="top-link-cart">My Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="Checkout" class="top-link-checkout">Checkout</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="Blog" class="top-link-blog">Blog</a> </li>
                <li class=" last"><a href="" title="Se connecter" >Se connecter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.header-container {
    position:fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
}
.header {
    text-align:right;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    z-index:10;
}
.header .quick-access {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.header .form-search {
    float:right;
    height:40px;
    width: auto;
    line-height:40px;
}
form {
    display: inline;
}
```

I found a way to do it with `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` but I don't want to use this technique because I want to support older browsers.

So how come the technique:

```
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
```

is only working with the ul list menu and not with the input and button?

UPDATE

Here is the jsfiddle link where you can see the problem: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fELkE/)

Comment: can you post your html code please, jsFiddle file is better for understanding.

Comment: Please post your HTML in the question, images are great for *support* (just like fiddles) but they're no replacement.

Comment: maybe use `vertical-align` for both elements...

Comment: I was ask to put the HTML... That's what I did. Give me a second here.

Comment: @Lukas sorry it does not work.

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu - there is no time limit on this site. Patience is a virtue that you do not possess.

Comment: @Neurofluxation: Letting it slide this time. People are mean. Just try not to let it happen again.

Comment: @Jean-Nicolas: When someone badgers you for a quick response, you can flag them. That sort of comment is unwarranted. I've cleared the rest of the offending comments now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest to not using line-height for this... It's not a text block.
Instead... I will use padding-top like this:

```
.header .form-search {
  float: right;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* FF */
  width: auto;
}
```

Update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/fELkE/1/

Comment: You're using padding-top. I am looking for a way to do it without margin and padding. Because in some browser it will look different I want true middle.

Comment: Oops.. I didn't read that in the main question, sorry. Now.. if you don't want to use `padding` or `margin` or `display:table-cell` and want to be fully cross-browser solution... I think you can't with `one magic solution`... Muy suggest then, Use the most modern solution, and `CSS hacks` for old browsers.

Comment: What CSS hacks? Can you add them to your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Sure.. tell me when (object && browser) this happends => *`Because in some browser it will look different`* (I already tested on `win+Chrome`, `win+FF`, `win+IE10/9` and look nice)

Comment: BTW, if both `.header .quick-access` && `.header .form-search` has a fixed `height`, why you don't want to use margin/padding?

Comment: In the past I have run into problems with other browsers. It seems that in some browsers the way the input is size changes... But also the trick of using height and line-heigh works: http://jsfiddle.net/53ALd/1606/ Why is it not working on my side?

Comment: Not even the fiddle?.... yours works well for me. In which OS & Browser are you testing.

Comment: Let's try something only to test... Install this extension [Disable Extensions Temporarily](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-extensions-tempor/lcfdefmogcogicollfebhgjiiakbjdje) in chrome and click on it... then open or refresh your [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/53ALd/1606/).... could be some external code that is affecting your page.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `float:left` to your `<h1>` element. This fixes the issue.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9LPew/2/)**

```
<header>
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
    </form>
    <button>Button</button>
</header>
```

### css

```
header
{
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%; 
    background: #ccc;
}
input,button,form
{
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
h1
{
    margin:0; padding:0;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I tried and it did not work... Plus when I changed the height of the input it went to the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/9LPew/3/